# Copying the contents of a div containing plain texts and select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a div whose contents are dynamically generated using a back end php script. The div  contains plain text as well as select menu (drop-down menu). I need to copy the contents (plain texts and the selected option from the menu) to a text area in the same page.

I searched a lot in stackoverflow got some answers too and tried following:
 1. .innerHTML of javascript but it copies the HTML code.
 2. .innerTEXT but it does not show the selected value from the list.
 3. clone function of ajax but it is not working on text area and generates the same selection     option if i try to copy the contents in another div.

Please someone help me to do this. A piece of code will be very much helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Some code would be helpfull...

Comment: You say innerHTML doesn't work as it contains HTML code, if you don't want the HTML included what output are you expecting?

Comment: I just want the contents to of the div to be copied in the text box.
e.g: div contains :
Nationality: <select name="abc"> <option value="India"> INDIA </option>
<option value="USA"> USA </option> <select>

Now when user selects INDIA from the list. I want 

Nationality: INDIA to be copied in the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like

```
var text=$("div").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
var selectValue=$("div").find("select").val();
$("input[type='text']").val("Text:"+text+"selectValue:"+selectValue);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/109/)

**Edit**

```
$("div").find("select").change(function () {
    var text = $("div").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text().trim();
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    $("input[type='text']").val(text + selectValue);
});
```

[**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/111/)

**Edit**

```
$("[name=div1]").find("select").change(function () {
    var text = $("div").contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });


    var finalValue = "";
    $("[name=div1]").find("select").each(function (i) {
        finalValue += $(text[i]).text().trim() + $(this).val();
    });
    $("input[type='text']").val(finalValue);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/112/)

Comment: @Ujjwal Prakash is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this i needed this only. Can you please guide me on how to do the same if the name of the div is "div1" and there are more than one select option say "s1", "s2", "s3" etc.

Comment: you want to get the value of which select?

Comment: Also there will be plain text after the select menu. example : 

Nationality : INDIA , GENDER : MALE, etc etc

Comment: i want to get the value of all selects

Comment: @UjjwalPrakash see the edit.Accept the answer if it meet the requirement

Comment: Thanks Anoop for this. instead of onload i want this action to be perfomed using onclick i.e there is a button and when user clicks it then the contents gets copied to the textarea

Comment: :This code do not work if there is no select option in the div. My backend script is dynamic and sometimes it do not sends any select option. also if there is some text after the select option your code dont display that

Comment: I've spent lot of time on your needs. Now i can't. Stack overflow is not such a community, Users wont write code for you according to your exact need. I've given you 3 different examples. Now you can utilize and analyze those code to satisfy your requirement

Comment: yeah i know, so can you please give me any link from where i can learn all these stuffs i am totally new to this.